# Create a COM using C# and .Net 5

Tags: c#, com, .net-5

I am trying to create a COM DLL that can be called (in my case) by Kofax Capture (document scanning) when exporting the scanned images to a document management system.

I am a Java programmer and have only limited knowledge of Microsoft dev tools. I have spent some days looking at the direction of MS development and it seems to me that the C# and .Net 5 is the way to go.

I have created various test projects and written some basic stub code but I can't get Kofax to see my DLL (Tools->Export Connectors>Add). It just says 'The DllRegister() call failed'. I assume this is because I have not coded my DLL correctly to be a valid COM. I have read a lot of posts but none seem to exactly fit what I'm trying to do. My latest attempt looks like:

KfxReleaseScript.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Kofax.ReleaseLib;

namespace IVAscentExpConn
{
    [Guid("04BF893F-B36E-4F53-A6A9-EDC506A315AD")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IKfxReleaseScript {
        ReleaseData DocumentData { get; set; }
        KfxReturnValue OpenScript();
        KfxReturnValue CloseScript();
        KfxReturnValue ReleaseDoc();
    }

    [Guid("F1264D82-F000-414A-9D06-C45F500B94E9")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("IVAscentExpConn.KfxReleaseScript")]
    public class KfxReleaseScript : IKfxReleaseScript {
        public KfxReleaseScript() {
        }

        public ReleaseData DocumentData { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public KfxReturnValue CloseScript() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public KfxReturnValue OpenScript() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public KfxReturnValue ReleaseDoc() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

KfxReleaseSetupScript.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Kofax.ReleaseLib;

namespace IVAscentExpConn
{
    [Guid("7E4BC84F-13E1-4317-B9B8-B2B2F09BC4FB")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IKfxReleaseSetupScript {
        ReleaseSetupData SetupData { get; set; }
        KfxReturnValue OpenScript();
        KfxReturnValue CloseScript();
        KfxReturnValue RunUI();
        KfxReturnValue ActionEvent(KfxActionValue action, string dataStringOne, string dataStringTwo);
    }

    [Guid("42A213E5-EA23-435C-8EDF-FB5913F2D495")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("IVAscentExpConn.KfxReleaseSetupScript")]
    public class KfxReleaseSetupScript : IKfxReleaseSetupScript {
        public KfxReleaseSetupScript() { }

        public ReleaseSetupData SetupData { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public KfxReturnValue ActionEvent(KfxActionValue action, string param1, string param2) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public KfxReturnValue CloseScript() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public KfxReturnValue OpenScript() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public KfxReturnValue RunUI() {
            Window1 w1 = new Window1();
            w1.Show();
            return (KfxReturnValue.KFX_REL_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
```

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Product>For Ascent</Product>
    <Company>My Comp Ltd</Company>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>Kofax export connector for our document management system.</Description>
    <Copyright>My Comp Ltd, 2021.</Copyright>
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    <EnableRegFreeCom>true</EnableRegFreeCom>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Kofax.ReleaseLib.Interop">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\Capture\Bin\Kofax.ReleaseLib.Interop.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have also tried:
C:\dev\dotnet\IVAscentExpConn\bin\Release\net5.0-windows>regsvr32 IVAscentExpConn.dll

but it says:

The module "IVAscentExpConn.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

My DLL does show a WPF panel but currently it is of the 'Hello World' variety and clearly I don't get that far yet.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `EnableComHosting` means you should be outputting a `IVAscentExpConn.comhost.dll`, that's what you would need to register, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Comment: use IVAscentExpConn.comhost.dll to register and make sure you're targeting the right bitness: 32-bits registry => .NET compile as x86, 64-bits registry => .NET compile as x64. If you want to support both bitness you'll have to distribute two versions of IVAscentExpConn.comhost.dll (unfortunately this is a new requirement for .NET 5 as opposed to .NET Framework)

Comment: @AlexK. I tried that and I can now register using regsvr32. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I tried that and set the Platform target to x86. Thanks very much.

Comment: Having registered fine, Kofax now gives me a different error (so I'm guessing progress). It now says "The Setup script object could not be created". I have checked the log and that is as helpful as it gets. I also tried removing all registry entries containing 'IVAscent', then registering again, and also tried cleaning my project and rebuilding, all to no avail alas. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This message doesn't smell like it's coming from Windows/COM, so it probably comes from what your object does. You can try to debug it, put logs, etc.

Comment: Could that simply be how it deals with the NotImplementedExceptions you throw?